# Synaptic Touchpad want no movement in button area 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, touchpad

I want to change my touchpad/synclient settings so that the mouse pointer does not move in the area at the bottom where the buttons are.  How would I do this on 12.04 LTS?

edit: I achieved the desired behavior by changing `AreaBottomEdge          = 0` using the command  `synclient AreaBottomEdge=3900` but at the (unacceptable) cost of the right mouse button behaving like the left mouse button.

```
user@notebook:~$ synclient
Parameter settings:

LeftEdge                = 1766
RightEdge               = 5378
TopEdge                 = 1627
BottomEdge              = 4331
FingerLow               = 25
FingerHigh              = 30
FingerPress             = 256
MaxTapTime              = 180
MaxTapMove              = 230
MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
SingleTapTimeout        = 180
ClickTime               = 100
FastTaps                = 0
EmulateMidButtonTime    = 0
EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
VertScrollDelta         = 104
HorizScrollDelta        = 104
VertEdgeScroll          = 1
HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
CornerCoasting          = 0
VertTwoFingerScroll     = 0
HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 0
MinSpeed                = 1
MaxSpeed                = 1.75
AccelFactor             = 0.0381316
TrackstickSpeed         = 40
EdgeMotionMinZ          = 30
EdgeMotionMaxZ          = 160
EdgeMotionMinSpeed      = 1
EdgeMotionMaxSpeed      = 419
EdgeMotionUseAlways     = 0
TouchpadOff             = 2
LockedDrags             = 0
LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
RTCornerButton          = 2
RBCornerButton          = 3
LTCornerButton          = 0
LBCornerButton          = 0
TapButton1              = 1
TapButton2              = 3
TapButton3              = 0
ClickFinger1            = 1
ClickFinger2            = 3
ClickFinger3            = 0
CircularScrolling       = 0
CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
CircScrollTrigger       = 0
CircularPad             = 0
PalmDetect              = 0
PalmMinWidth            = 10
PalmMinZ                = 200
CoastingSpeed           = 20
CoastingFriction        = 50
PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
ResolutionDetect        = 1
GrabEventDevice         = 1
TapAndDragGesture       = 1
AreaLeftEdge            = 0
AreaRightEdge           = 0
AreaTopEdge             = 0
AreaBottomEdge          = 0
HorizHysteresis         = 8
VertHysteresis          = 8
ClickPad                = 1
RightButtonAreaLeft     = 3572
RightButtonAreaRight    = 0
RightButtonAreaTop      = 3984
RightButtonAreaBottom   = 0
MiddleButtonAreaLeft    = 0
MiddleButtonAreaRight   = 0
MiddleButtonAreaTop     = 0
MiddleButtonAreaBottom  = 0
```

Comment: Creating a /etc/X11/xorg.conf file with the following made the touchpad less annoying: Option "FingerLow" "30" Option "FingerHigh" "35" Option "HorizHysteresis" "40" Option "VertHysteresis" "40".  Note that this is not a complete xorg.conf